# AppCenter needs to accept PayPal

Tags: appcenter

I thought the idea of the **AppCenter** was a great idea, until the first time I had to pay for something.

I'm not complaining about how much, or that you want a payment, but that I can't use my **PayPal**.

Like it or not... this is how the poor consumers of the world buy stuff.
I'm more than a little bent out of shape that you'll only take credit cards.

Please add more transaction options than just a credit card.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this is not the place for such a proposal - stackexchange is a question and answer comunity where people can share experience how the things work or not. If you want to ask for such a payment option, the official way to do it is to add an issue into https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have to pay for anything unless you want to. The AppCenter is pay-what-you-want store, so if you don’t have money or that you cannot pay for any reason like in your case your only option is PayPal which is currently unavailable you can just change its price to zero then download it.